# Code injection in webapplication using .net, java and php

Tags: java, php, .net, xss, code-injection

I need to do a presentation on code injection on webapplication and how to prevent it. I am not too familiar with .net, and I mostly know about code injection on SQL or php.

Reading and searching the web it seems that between java, .net, and php code injection is easiest in php, then in java (dynamically loading scrips), but in .net I do not find that many or so well documented.

Would it be possible to have an (easy) example of code injection in .net and maybe how to prevent it. Also any links to code injection in java or php would also be great, you can never read enough.

For example I have for java:

Java (using javax.script.*)

```
<% String pageToInclude = getDataFromUntrustedSource(); %> 
<jsp:include page=" <%=pageToInclude %>" />
```

Is there anythign apart from input validation that works specificly in this frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

@ .net by default the framework is protect your page.
you need to valid all textboxs when submit page it does't include any special charter

Comment: Correct. Maybe I am too lost, but I dont see how even if I let any input go through the application will run undesire code. For example in java without loading and running scripts dynamically. If a String is 
"; System.out.println("this is my second name")\ 
 then it will still print that string, since it makes it into string before processing.